# Where there are two or more people named, this data protection statement applies to each person separately

Tags: grammar

This expression is in a statement of a bank. What make me confused is the function of the where clause. Where here I think, precedes a adverbial clause, but seem not like a adverbial clause of place, more like a adverbial clause of condition.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to hazard an answer as an attorney (because I am one) and because I think this phrase goes to an effort at describing a legal condition. The statement is describing something known in U.S. law as "joint and several," an adjectival phrase meaning "apportionable either among two or more parties or to only one or a few select members of the group...together and in separation." (Black's Law Dictionary 7th ed.) Simply put that means, as far as the protections articulated in the statement, the protection applies to everyone together, as a group or collective,and also individually. 
As for the grammatical use of "Where," here it would be locative as it is referring to where *in the statement/contract* "two or more people are named," although in broader meaning you are not incorrect in thinking that the "where" functions more along the lines of *when* such a condition applies, as described with the two or more people in the statement. In such a case then the "protection statement" applies to them jointly and severally, meaning, not only in the instance of all of the person's collective protection working as an entity, but each individual's separate protectable interest.
Thinking outside of legalese for a moment though, consider this biblical verse: "For where two or three are gathered together in my name, there am I in the midst of them." Matthew 18:20 King James Version. Here the verb "gathered" tells you the locative "where" is in effect; physically where people are gathered together, Jesus says to his disciples he is with them. In your example what seems to be confusing is "where...named" but that is a legal convention. If the phrase said, "when...named" it would seem to suggest a temporal aspect that is inapplicable. I am of the opinion that this construction and use of "where," used to refer to a citation in a statement, rather than a physical place, itself referring to a condition, is restricted to legal usage, as a lay writer would not likely use it. I can tell you also such a construction is fairly common in legal drafting.

Comment: Thank you for warm help. I can get some where usage in dictionaries as a conditional clause meaning in a case in which. In this case, how we differentiate where and if- clause?

Comment: Good question. "Where" in this example does not strictly speaking function as a conditional, although it may seem to have that meaning.  The difference is that an if conditional retains the possibility that it may not occur. "If it rains, I will get soaked." It may not rain. However, in common English, where can sometimes be used to mean the same thing: "Where there is smoke, there is also fire," means, "If" you see smoke, you can assume there will be fire." However in a legal document, "if" specifically retains an open possibility. "Where" in your example denotes that it has happened.

Comment: Along your line, what does " if there is smoke" and "where there is smoke" differ?

Comment: That is mainly just a difference in idiomatic usage. The expression in English is "where there is smoke," not "if there is smoke." However they mean almost identical ideas.